# Dynamically create button for each div with class name, and create show/hide on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to come up with a nice solution to easily add menu pages.
Each menu page should be a div with the class 'shTab' to identify that it is a show/hide element, I also want to give each div a unique name, so I can create buttons with that name as text.

I'm creating each div with hard coded html, and I want a jQuery function to first get all the div's and put then in my array tabs.

I then want to iterate over the tabs array and for each div I will create a button which should be appended to the buttonContainer class, so that all the buttons will be in the same area like a normal menu.

I also want for each button created to make a on click function that will .hide() all the tabs, and at last .show() the tab which belongs to the clicked button.

I have tried to get it to work in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s609c9a6/) but I am runnig into problems with my div element when trying to iterate over them (i think thats the problem).

**html**

```
<div class='buttonContainer'>

</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='shTab' name='home'>
    <p>Homepage! yay</p>
  </div>
  <div class='shTab' name='contact'>
    <p>Contact page! yay</p>
  </div>
  <div class='shTab' name='images'>
    <p>no images yet :(</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**javaScript**

```
var tabs = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div.shTab').each(function(i, obj) {
        tabs.push(obj);
  });

  for (var div in tabs) {
    div.hide();
    $('.buttonContainer').append(
            $('<button/>', {
          text: div.name,
          click: function () {
            for (var div in tabs) {
              div.hide();
            }
            this.show();
          }
      })
    );
  }

});
```

I notice that the 'div' object within my for loop doesn't work as a jQuery object, .hide(), .name .... etc. doesn't work as I intent.

What I'm i doing wrong ?

Comment: I created a fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/yxg3w9u8/ ) ... Maybe it helps somehow. But please note, that I don't like query so I only used JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, i modified you code, and now it does almost what i want. (https://jsfiddle.net/yxg3w9u8/2/) still, would prefer a jQuery version. but... this is better than nothing! thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

Same thing, done via jQuery. **[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/yxg3w9u8/3/)**, if you need.

```js
// Create the tabs collection...
var tabs = $('.shTab');
// create the buttons, based on the tabs themselves
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  // wrap the individual tab in the jQuery object.
  var tab = $(tabs[i]);
  // use the tab's name attribute for the button text.
  var btn = $('<button>').html(tab.attr("name"));
  // hide the current tab.
  tab.hide();
  // Add the button to the containing div.
  $('.buttonContainer').append(btn);
}
/*****
 * event listener for the click
 *   NOTE: Because I've added the buttons dynamically,
 *    I can't simply listen to them as a set. I can
 *    either re-create the listener with each button,
 *    or use EVENT DELEGATION!
 *****/
$(".buttonContainer").on("click", "button", function() {
  // use the index of the clicked button to index the
  //  appropriate tab.
  var buttonIndex = $(this).index();
  var tab = $(tabs[buttonIndex]);

  // Show the current tab...
  tab.show()
    // ... and hide all the siblings!
    .siblings().hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='buttonContainer'>

</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='shTab' name='home'>
    <p>Homepage! yay</p>
  </div>
  <div class='shTab' name='contact'>
    <p>Contact page! yay</p>
  </div>
  <div class='shTab' name='images'>
    <p>no images yet :(</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! interesting solution with the button click action created like that! Would never have thought of that, and I also did not know the .siblings() existed. However I managed to come up with a solution my self as well, based on my own try and @christian's plain js try. If you can argument which of our solutions is "best" please let me know!

Comment: Don't really know if there's a 'best' to this, it's a matter of personal preference. I prefer to use a single jQuery object (for the tabs variable), and pull out each tab as needed -- but that approach requires that I wrap it in a jQuery object when I extract it, each time. Also, I don't care for having the same listener in multiple places -- you re-instantiate it for each button. Instead, I have a single listener. But again, personal taste.

Comment: Yeah, was just wondering how the two solutions compete on a performance aspect? I'm not sure if having a ton of registered listeners is bad practice?

Comment: do you plan on hundreds of thousands of tabs? if so, then yup, serious performance hit. But its more the potential of a memory leak. By having a single listener, regardless of how many possible elements being listened to, I have a very very tiny memory footprint.

Comment: Alright, thanks. That answer my concerns. I'm having 10-15 of them, so that is gonna be minimal memory consumption

Comment: sounds like. If what you got works, and you understand WHY it works, run with it. But in future, tinker with siblings() -- stuff like that is FUN!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by looking at all the help. Thanks a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tabs = [];

 $('div.shTab').each(function(i, obj) {
        tabs.push($(obj));
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
   tabs[i].hide();
    $('.buttonContainer').append(
  $('<button/>', {
          text: tabs[i].attr('name'),
          click: function (event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
              tabs[i].hide();
              if(tabs[i].attr('name') === event.target.innerHTML){
                tabs[i].show();
              }
            }
          }
      })
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='buttonContainer'>

</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='shTab' name='home'>
    <p>Homepage! yay</p>
  </div>
  <div class='shTab' name='contact'>
    <p>Contact page! yay</p>
  </div>
  <div class='shTab' name='images'>
    <p>no images yet :(</p>
  </div>
</div>
```